# openlayers 6 how to get a value from an array for a text label

Tags: arrays, gis, openlayers, postgis

I am trying to create a label in openlayers. ( pop-ups I can do) .
My data comes from a PostgreSQL db.

I managed to create an array with the values like this:

```
var selectedFeatures = [];
ogc.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
  selectedFeatures.push(feature.get("id"),feature.get("datum"),feature.get("fractie"), feature.get("tijd"));
});;
```

Now, how do I match the actual feature (id), with the right value (id)from the array?
And push this value to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object instead of an array, or an array of arrays indexed by the id

```
  selectedFeatures[feature.get("id")] = [feature.get("datum"),feature.get("fractie"), feature.get("tijd")];
```